# ReflectionException in Route.php line 335: Function () does not exist don't know why

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning Laravel framework and I have created simple project.

This is my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/people', ['uses' => 'PeopleController@index']);
```

**PeopleController.php**

```
class PeopleController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $users = [

        '0' =>[
            'first' => 'Alex',
            'last' => 'Shifu',
            'location' => 'Gotham'
        ]
    ];

    return view('people.index' , compact('people'));
}
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($people as $peep)
    <li>{!! $peep['first'] !!}</li>
@endforeach
```

These are the errors I am facing:

> in RouteCollection.php line 161 at
>   RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766 at
>   Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621 at
>   Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607 at
>   Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268 at
>   Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 53 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46 at
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 104 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php
>   line 150 at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in
>   Kernel.php line 117 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php
>   line 54 at require_once('C:\wamp64\www\MyApp\public\index.php') in
>   server.php line 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see is that you have to change $users to $people in your index() method.

Other than that, everything looks fine.